# The following _TypeError was thrown building -Exception caught by widgets library

Tags: flutter

> The following _TypeError was thrown building

> BlurImagePageScaffold(dirty): type 'List' is not a subtype of
> type 'Widget'

I'm getting above error when Im trying to run my code. I have included my codes files below.  how to solve this.

> blur_image_page_scaffold.dart

```
import 'dart:ui';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class BlurImagePageScaffold extends StatelessWidget {
  const BlurImagePageScaffold({Key? key,this.imagePath, this.body}) : super(key: key);
   final body;
   final imagePath;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      height: double.infinity,
      width: double.infinity,
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        shape: BoxShape.rectangle,
        image: DecorationImage(
            image: AssetImage(imagePath),fit: BoxFit.fill),
      ),
      child: BackdropFilter(
        filter: ImageFilter.blur(sigmaX:10, sigmaY:10),
        child: Container(
          color: Colors.black.withOpacity(0),
          child: Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
            children: [
                     body
                ],
              )
          ),
        ),
      );

  }
}
```

> hello.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:new_chat_app/components/blur_image_page_scaffold.dart';
import 'package:new_chat_app/components/lets_start.dart';
import 'package:new_chat_app/components/logo.dart';
import 'package:new_chat_app/components/terms_and_conditions.dart';

class Hello extends StatelessWidget {
  const Hello({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return BlurImagePageScaffold(imagePath: 'images/bg.jpg', body: [
      Logo(),
      Column(
        children: [
          Text('Hello'),
          Column(
            children: [
              Text("Whatsapp is a Cross-Platform"),
              Text("mobile messaging with friends"),
              Text("all over the world"),
            ],
          ),
          TermsAndConditions(),
          LetsStart(),
        ],
      ),
    ]);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply set `children` to `body`

Like so:

```
BackdropFilter(
        filter: ImageFilter.blur(sigmaX:10, sigmaY:10),
        child: Container(
          color: Colors.black.withOpacity(0),
          child: Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
            children: body,
              )
          ),
        ),
      )
```